# div style change on click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some div i want change selective div position to center means suppose I select the first two div only that div text move to `center` on click

```js
$("#key").click(function myfunction() {
  $("div").css("text-align", center);
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">clickme</button>
<div onselect="myfunction()">blabla</div>
<div onselect="myfunction()">cat</div>
<div onselect="myfunction()">rose</div>
```

Comment: `$("div").css("text-align",'center')`

Comment: as far as I know the onselect event is not supported on div elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select.  please provide  clear specification of steps to reproduce the 'bug' that you currently have. what exact user actions are meant to trigger the expected behavior?

Comment: $("div") targets all div elements on the page. is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give name to click `function`. It can be anonymous. Also it should be `$("div").css("text-align", 'center')` to assign a `css` property.

```js
function myfunction() {
    //Not sure why you have this on div.
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#key").click(function() {
    $("div").css("text-align", 'center')
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">clickme</button>
<div onselect="myfunction()">blabla</div>
<div onselect="myfunction()">cat</div>
<div onselect="myfunction()">rose</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Set(`toggle`) `selected` class on `click` of element
- Remove `inline` event `onselect`
- Set `center` property to only those elements which are having `selected` class
- Set property in `quotes`, **`$("div").css("text-align", 'center');`**

```js
$("#key").click(function myfunction() {
  $("div.toGrab:not(.selected)").css("text-align", '');
  $("div.selected").css("text-align", 'center');
});

$("div.toGrab").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">clickme</button>
<div class='toGrab'>blabla</div>
<div class='toGrab'>cat</div>
<div class='toGrab'>rose</div>
```

Comment: actually i want move only the selected div means suppose i select first two div(select means using mouse)
if i select 2 div .that div only move to centre , the unselect div remain the same position

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor miss, need to assign value as string as shown below:

```
$("#key").click(function() {
   $("div").css("text-align", "center");
});
```

If you want to give margin than also number will be specified as string as:

```
$("#key").click(function() {
   $("div").css("padding", "50");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`@aswathy` your all code is okay, only you missed `"text-align", 'center'`

> `center` property should be in single quotes

```js
  $("#key").click(function myfunction() {
    $("div").css("text-align", 'center');
  });
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">clickme</button>
<div onselect="myfunction()">blabla</div>
<div onselect="myfunction()">cat</div>
<div onselect="myfunction()">rose</div>
```